# is_user_logged_in not working to redirect only logged out users

Tags: functions, login, wp-redirect

So I have the code below in my functions.php file.  It works for logged out users but it also redirects users that are logged in.  Can anyone help?

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );
function redirect_to_specific_page() {
    if ( is_paged() || is_author() || is_single()  && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_redirect( 'http://www.exampleblog.net/members-only/', 301 );
        exit;
    }
}
```

I'm using this to redirect all logged out users to a page where it tells them they have to be logged in to view other pages (Pages 2, 3 and so on.  Also for them not to view author's page and archives when they click authors name).

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap the first three `||` conditions in additional parentheses so they are evaluated first **BEFORE** the last `&&` condition:

**Psuedocode example:**

```
    here                               here 
     ↓                                  ↓  
if ( (condition || condtion || condition) && ! condition ) {
    //do business logic...
}
```

**This now means that:**

If any **ONE** of `is_paged()` **OR** `is_author()` **OR** `is_single()` **IS** `true` **THEN** evaluate the second condition `! is_user_logged_in()`

**In your original code:**

With no additional parentheses wrapping the first three conditions, **IF** any of those four conditions return `true` then you would redirect your user whether they are logged in or not.

**Final code with additional parentheses:**

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );

function redirect_to_specific_page() {   
    if ( (is_paged() || is_author() || is_single()) && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_redirect( 'http://www.exampleblog.net/members-only/', 301 ); exit; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: @ineedhelp Good to hear, feel free to mark this answer as correct/complete.